# What is Default Browser in PHP get_browser?

Tags: php, default-browser

I see search results in SO of get_browser resulting `Default Browser` for example Chrome Users, I on the other hand am not sure of what the users are using I think `Default Browser` results in my case are robots/crawlers/etc.

I'm using the `full_php_browscap.ini` version and it gets a `Default Browser` value for the browser. What is `Default Browser`? And when does get_browser return `Default Browser`?

Comment: this should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902438/get-browser-in-chrome-returns-default-browser

Comment: already saw that. what I want to know is what is `Default Browser` and when does get_browser return `Default Browser`

Comment: You likely do not have your` php.ini` configured to use the `full_php.browsecap.ini` file. Where is your file located and what are the PHP config settings(s) you have for it? When it can't find the file is it suppose to give default browser as far as I know.

Comment: @crypticツ I actually have php.ini [browscap] set to `browscap = /public_html/_php/full_php_browscap.ini` and `full_php_browscap.ini` is also located at the path `/public_html/_php/` . Am I missing something?

Comment: If the browser sends an unknown user agent string, or even doesn't send one at all, then there's no way that PHP can know anything about the browser. This can happen if they're using an proxy that strips out the UA or if they change it deliberately. It's also possible to set most browsers to pretend to be a different browser. It is important to understand that at the server end you cannot be certain of what browser is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'Default Browser' is returned when the user-agent is unknown. Either the agent is missing from browscap or maybe browscap can't be found.

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to find out wich user-agent was used. Maybe this string is just made up (robots indeed).

Someone replied the folowing on the php manual page for get_browser:

> We are using get_browser() function for useragent Mozilla/4.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT) the get_browser function is
>   returning as Default Browser and Platform = unknown.
>
> So i added this to my browscap.ini manually:
>
> [Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)] Parent=IE 4.01
>   Platform=WinNT

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted much time to learn how to use that func,

While I finally understood that man should never use that function, 
it will kill your performance !!!

try with/without get_browser to check the result.

```
ab -c 100 -n 100 http://yourserver/
```

use `preg_match_all('/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` instead

Comment: "should never use that function". Caveat, I find it useful for debugging in error logs.